# How to open a Slack huddle directly from the command line?

Tags: slack

I would like to join a daily Slack Huddle meeting from crontab.  How should I call `slack`?

The URL obtained via *Copy huddle link* (starting with "https://app.slack.com/huddle/..."), that works with the web browser indeed, doesn't work when applied directly to the Slack binary.  And I would like to skip the navigator because of its disadvantages:

- it requires $DISPLAY to be defined
- it leaves a trampoline webpage open

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a slack:-URL.

You can convert the one you get with "Copy huddle link" as follows:

```
sed 's|^https://app\.slack\.com/huddle/\([^/]\+\)/\(.*\)$|slack://join-huddle?team=\1\&id=\2|'
```

Which converts `https://app.slack.com/huddle/<TEAM>/<ID>` into: `slack://join-huddle?team=<TEAM>&id=<ID>`.

Now you can add this to your crontab (by typing `crontab -e`):

`30 9 * * 1-5 slack 'slack://join-huddle?team=<TEAM>&id=<ID>'`

(Beware the **quotation marks**, since there is an ampersand in the URL)

A nice thing is that, in any case, slack will show a confirmation dialog before entering the call.